# Isolate hoots seen in spectrogram

Tags: audacity, spectrogram

I have an audio file of an owl hooting. The hoots are barely audible. If I look at the spectrogram in Audacity I can see them. They are the blips at 0.5k

[image: spectrogram]

How can I isolate these?

Edit:
High pass 400, Low pass 700. Noise reduction. Spectral Deletaion.Better.
Just need to amplify now.
[image: better]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a [high pass](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/high_pass_filter.html) and [low pass](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/low_pass_filter.html) filter, and [noise reduction](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/noise_reduction.html). Then amplify the result if needed.

For the high pass filter try a frequency of 400 Hz and for the low pass try 700 Hz. This gives you the segment of 400-700 Hz where your hooting signal seems to be. For noise reduction profile select a part where there is no hooting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. See my edit to question, please.

Comment: Well, then just use the amplify effect: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/amplify.html It automatically sets the maximum that's working for the peak.